# Angular momentum about a point in translation

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, angular-momentum, rotational-dynamics, reference-frames, angular-velocity

Consider the following question which was asked in JEE Advanced 2016:

[image]

Consider the first option(which is the third option [here](https://youtu.be/TxXuo9ukVxU?t=874))

In the video linked above, Tibees takes $L_{com}=L_1+L_2$ where $L_1$ & $L_2$ are the angular momenta caused by the rotation of the two discs about the line joining them.

My question is this- why is the angular momentum caused by translation of the system(since the system rotates about axis perpendicular to line joining them, which would provide a velocity $v$) not considered? It would give two additional angular momentum quantities

Comment: Tibees has made a lot of mistakes in that solution and her video should not be taken seriously.

Answer (score 2):

What you are asking can be rephrased as: "why do we not include the angular momentum due to the center of mass motion of the rod?"

Keep in mind that the angular momentum has to be defined relative to an origin. Option A (sneakily) states that the origin to consider is not $O$ but the center of mass (COM). Therefore the distance from the origin to the COM is zero, and the angular momentum due to the COM motion $\vec{L}_{\rm COM}=m \vec{r}_{\rm COM} \times \vec{v}_{\rm COM}=0$.

Comment: Its been a long time since I have touched rigid body dynamics. Planning to restart it, I'm trying to assemble every fact that I know. The reason why Im saying all this is because I might want you to personally address a few questions: Its randomly given in my book that the angular momentum of a body about a fixed point(origin) $L=L_{spin}+L_{motion}$ where $L_{spin}$ is the angular momentum of the body about its center of mass. It is very easy to understand it using the example of a rolling wheel.

Comment: However there are some cases where a body rotates about some other axis(say a rod rotating about its end around the $y$ axis). Does the relation still hold good? What does $I_{com}$ here even signify? Im completely thrown off by this seemingly simple question. A guidance in the right direction is appreciated. [Reference pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hTIjX.png)

Comment: The very idea of imagining $I_{com}$ here is scary, not to mention confusing @Andrew

Comment: @newbie105 I didn't use the symbol $I_{\rm com}$ :-) You can define it but it will be a singular function and I'm not sure it is a very useful concept if you are reviewing basics of mechanics. Just stick with the angular momentum of a point particle, $\vec{L} = m \vec{r} \times \vec{v}$, where $m$ is the mass of the particle, $\vec{r}$ is the vector from the origin to the particle, and $\vec{v}$ is the velocity.

Comment: I wish I can, but these types of questions are pretty common in the exams and I havent the slightest idea what to do.

Comment: Sorry actually I'm wrong, the moment of inertia is actually just $mr^2$ for a point particle. If you want to write it as an integral, the integrand will be singular, but that probably isn't relevant.

Comment: The thing bothering me is the axis of rotation. It is asked to always take moment of inertia about the center of mass regardless of the axis of rotation in the scenario. I couldnt digest this fact

Comment: Computing the moment of inertia relative to the COM makes sense if you want to evaluate $L_{\rm spin}$, since spin is rotation about the center of mass.